# Receive webRTC video stream using python OpenCV in real-time

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, opencv, webrtc

Hi,
I am creating a pipeline where I need to access data from the camera and do some OpenCV algorithms in it. I am able to send the video from the source using webRTC. https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2014/03/13/build-a-local-webcam-with-webrtc-in-less-than-20-lines/

But, What I need help with is how to receive the video stream in Python and do the processing. How can I access the video feed from a webRTC stream to the Python backend?

This is the javascript code running.

```
(function(){
  var mediaOptions = { audio: false, video: true };

  if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
  }

  if (!navigator.getUserMedia){
    return alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');
  }

  navigator.getUserMedia(mediaOptions, success, function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

  function success(stream){
    var video = document.querySelector("#player");
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  }
})();
```

I need help in receiving the video from this Javascript using Python.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm the author of aiortc. Have you checked out the `server` example, as it illustrates how to process video using OpenCV?

https://github.com/jlaine/aiortc/tree/master/examples/server

Comment: I tried installing aiortc in Ubuntu 14.04 and was not able. Installed  it in ubuntu 16.04 and works well to my use case. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: This is a good example to process video from the own device. However, how do you let a foreign device send the video to this server?

Comment: @jeremy is it correct that there is no Windows support?

Comment: There is nothing to prevent you from using aiortc on Windows, but it involves compiling ffmpeg / libvpx / libopus so it's probably tedious

Comment: @JohnAndrews Were you able to process video from a foreign device?

Comment: I can NEVER use this at all for some reasons. Connected with no media flow :( ...!

Answer (score 3):

https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-cv-tensorflow/ shows a fairly in-depth tutorial for doing WebRTC + tensorflow. You can probably swap out tensorflow for opencv easily. This captures a frame from the webcam and sends it using HTTP every once in a while. If you want to go more realtime than that you will have to use WebRTC on the server, e.g. using https://github.com/jlaine/aiortc

Comment: I need it in real-time. I had went through this aiortc but the receiving part is not clear in the documentation. Have you tried it?

Comment: This only uses the media capture APIs but it's not using RTCPeerConnection anywhere.