# reading video stream in python from URL

Tags: python, web, computer-vision

I want to do facial recognition from a video conference website that gives a link for a video stream
URL : 'https://vklass.site:5443/Coe_class/play.html?name=mergedStream'
The problem is, I could not read the video from the URL in python
I tried cv2.videoCapture but it didn't work
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you fetched that page using `wget` or `curl` and looked at the source?  That's an HTML page.  It starts a Javascript WebRTC player using an HTML5 `<video>` tag.  You might look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187474/receive-webrtc-video-stream-using-python-opencv-in-real-time .